# database synchronization issue in multiple zencart site

Tags: php, database, zen-cart

I have 2 zencart site running and 3rd one is about to be live. I want each **user registration** and **coupon** will be available across those 3 sites. Actually I want user registration globally so user can access any site among these 3 with same login info. And update specific coupon info of any user if any changes has been made by him. Is it possible? pls share any idea you have. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about having 3 separate databases but share customers and coupons tables
I've done something similar